# Parsing mixed list with SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

Within the `<Images>` tag, [this API call](http://wiki.thegamesdb.net/index.php?title=GetGame) returns a mix of different types: fanart, boxart, banner, screenshot, clearlogo.

Using SimpleXML Framework, what is the best way to go about parsing those into separate Lists? I'd like a `List<FanArt>`, `List<BoxArt>`, `List<Banner>` etc. The [examples](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php) on the site do not seem to cover this situation. I've fumbled about with a few different ideas, but I'm not even sure SimpleXML Framework can handle this in a straight forward way.

For example, the below throws this exception:  *org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation of name 'Images' on field 'clearLogos'.....*

```
@ElementList(name = "Images", entry = "clearlogo")
private List<ClearLogo> clearLogos;

@ElementList(name = "Images", entry = "boxart")
private List<BoxArt> boxart;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this and needs some sort of solution, I've done this for now to get it working. Does the job but it's not really what I was after.

```
@Root
public class Images {

@ElementListUnion({
        @ElementList(entry = "fanart", type = FanArt.class, inline = true),
        @ElementList(entry = "boxart", type = BoxArt.class, inline = true),
        @ElementList(entry = "screenshot", type = ScreenShot.class, inline = true),
        @ElementList(entry = "banner", type = Banner.class, inline = true),
        @ElementList(entry = "clearlogo", type = ClearLogo.class, inline = true)
})
private List<Object> images;

private List<FanArt> fanarts;

private List<BoxArt> boxarts;

private List<ScreenShot> screenshots;

private List<Banner> banners;

private List<ClearLogo> clearlogos;

public List<FanArt> getFanarts() {
    if (fanarts == null) {
        fanarts = new ArrayList<FanArt>();
        for (Object image : images) {
            if (image instanceof FanArt) {
                fanarts.add((FanArt) image);
            }
        }
    }
    return fanarts;
}

public List<BoxArt> getBoxarts() {
    if (boxarts == null) {
        boxarts = new ArrayList<BoxArt>();
        for (Object image : images) {
            if (image instanceof BoxArt) {
                boxarts.add((BoxArt) boxarts);
            }
        }
    }
    return boxarts;
}

public List<ScreenShot> getScreenshots() {
    if (screenshots == null) {
        screenshots = new ArrayList<ScreenShot>();
        for (Object image : images) {
            if (image instanceof ScreenShot) {
                screenshots.add((ScreenShot) image);
            }
        }
    }
    return screenshots;
}

public List<Banner> getBanners() {
    if (banners == null) {
        banners = new ArrayList<Banner>();
        for (Object image : images) {
            if (image instanceof Banner) {
                banners.add((Banner) image);
            }
        }
    }
    return banners;
}

public List<ClearLogo> getClearLogos() {
    if (clearlogos == null) {
        clearlogos = new ArrayList<ClearLogo>();
        for (Object image : images) {
            if (image instanceof ClearLogo) {
                clearlogos.add((ClearLogo) image);
            }
        }
    }
    return clearlogos;
}
}
```